# discord.js bot for dueling other players

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a bot that will allow users to challenge others to duels. Currently I'm stuck with getting the bot to only show the duel as accepted if it is from the challenged user. As is, it will only allow responses from the original message sender. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if(command === `${prefix}fight`) {
    //checks if the username to fight is in the message
    let author1 = message.author.username;
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!user) return message.reply("you did not specify who you would like to fight!");

    //checks if the users is trying to fight themselves
    if(user.id == message.author.id) return message.reply('you cannot fight yourself!');

    //checks if the user is trying to fight the bot
    if(user.bot ==  true)
        return message.reply('you cannot fight a bot!');

    //saves the two user ids to variables
    var fighter1 = message.author.id;
    var fighter2 = user.id;

    //announces challenge and awaits response
    var challenged = user.toString();
    message.channel.send(`${challenged}, ${author1} has challenged you to a duel. Do you accept the challenge, yes or no?`)
        .then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content == 'yes' && message.author.id == fighter2 || response.content == 'no' && message.author.id == fighter2, {
                max: 1,
                time: 60000,
                errors: ['time'],
            })
            .then((collected) => {
                if (collected.first().content == 'yes') {
                    message.channel.send(`${challenged} has accepted the challenge!`);
                }
                else if(collected.first().content == 'no') {
                    message.channel.send(`nope`);
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                message.channel.send(`No response. Fight has been cancelled.`);
            });
        });       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your filter function is only looking at the `response` message when checking the `content`, but when you're checking `.author.id`, you get it from the original `message` that started the fight (which came from the challenger, not the person being challenged).

Try changing your filter function to use `response.author.id` instead of `message.author.id`, like this:

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content == 'yes' && response.author.id == fighter2 || response.content == 'no' && response.author.id == fighter2, {
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `message.author` instead of `response.author`

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(response => return (response.content == 'yes' && message.author.id == fighter2)
|| (response.content == 'no' && message.author.id == fighter2), 
{
    max: 1,
    time: 60000,
    errors: ['time'],
})
```